# JavaScript/jQuery - Check if string contains one of the keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to test if string contains on of the selected keywords?

For example

```
var keywords = 'small, big, large'
var string = 'big brown bear';

function wordInString(string, keywords){
  return new RegExp( '\\b' + keywords + '\\b', 'i').test(string);
}
```

The above only works for a single word, I need to be able to test multiple words, and exact match.

Comment: when you say multiple words, then order of words doesn't matter ryt?

Comment: That's correct, the order is not important.

Comment: Also if all are present only then you are required to return or even if single word is found then need to return?

Comment: split, each and IndexOf  function of Javascript/jquery is your answer

Comment: @AJ it will,always be just one keyword that is matched or none for that matter, but never multiple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the string into words, and use an array of keywords

```js
function wordInString(string, keywords) {
    return string.split(/\b/).some(Array.prototype.includes.bind(keywords));
}

var keywords = ['small', 'big', 'large'];
var result1  = wordInString('big brown bear', keywords);   // true
var result2  = wordInString('great brown bear', keywords); // false
var result3  = wordInString('Big brown bear', keywords);   // false

console.log(result1, result2, result3);
```

ES5 (cross-browser) version

```
function wordInString(string, keywords) {
    return string.split(/\b/).filter(function(w) {
        return keywords.indexOf(w) !== -1;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

---

To return all the words

```js
function wordInString(string, keywords) {
   return keywords.filter(function(x) { return this.includes(x) }, string.split(/\b/));
}

var keywords = ['small', 'big', 'large'];
var result1  = wordInString('big brown bear large', keywords); //  ["big", "large"]
var result2  = wordInString('great brown bear', keywords);     //  []
var result3  = wordInString('Big brown bear', keywords);       //  []

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

To return the first matching word or an empty string

```js
function wordInString(string, keywords) {
 var r = "";
    string.split(/\b/).some( x => {
     return r = keywords.includes(x) ? x : "";
    })
    return r;
}

var keywords = ['small', 'big', 'large'];
var result1  = wordInString('big brown bear large', keywords); //  "big"
var result2  = wordInString('great brown bear', keywords);     //  ""
var result3  = wordInString('Big brown bear', keywords);       //  ""

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in firebug 'TypeError: Array.prototype.includes is undefined'

Comment: @Alko - your browser isn't up to date, Firefox supports `includes` from version 43 and up, added a ES5 version as well.

Comment: Ok, second ES5 version works fine, just one more problem, it returns true/false, I need to return the actual keyword if true, or an empty string if false.

Comment: That's not really what the question says, but okay, just the first keyword, or all keywords that match

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of keywords, and loop through them:

```js
var keywords = ['small', 'big', 'large'];

console.log( wordInString("big brown bear", keywords) );            // true
console.log( wordInString("it's small!", keywords) );               // true
console.log( wordInString("it's larger than the other", keywords) );// false
console.log( wordInString("it's black and red", keywords) );        // false

function wordInString(string, keywords){
  for(var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++){
    if(new RegExp( '\\b' + keywords[i] + '\\b', 'i').test(string)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns matched word or preset string if not found.

```js
function wordInString(string, keywords) {
  return string.split(/\b/).filter(word => keywords.some(w => w === word))[0] || 'empty';
}

var keywords = ['small', 'big', 'large'];
var result1  = wordInString('big brown bear', keywords);   // big
var result2  = wordInString('tiny bear', keywords); // empty
var result3  = wordInString('huge hairy bear', keywords);   // empty

console.log(result1, result2, result3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution using `map`,`reduce` functions and `logical operators`.

```js
var keywords = 'small, big, large'
var test1  = testString('big brown bear', keywords);   //big
var test2  = testString('great brown bear', keywords); // empty
var test3  = testString('Big brown bear', keywords);   // empty
function wordInString(string, keywords){
  return new RegExp( '\\b' + keywords + '\\b').test(string);
}

function testString(string,keywords){
    var word='empty';
    var result=keywords.split(',').map(function(item){
        if(wordInString(string,item.trim())==true)
            word=item.trim();
        return wordInString(string,item.trim());  
    }).reduce(function(curr,prev){
        return curr || prev;
    });
    return word;
 }
console.log(test1)
console.log(test2)
console.log(test3)
```

Comment: @Alko, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split the keywords and then search `indexOf` of keywords on the string.

```js
var keywords = 'small, big, large'
var string = 'big brown bear';

function wordInString(string, keywords) {
  return keywords.split(',').some(function(keyword) {
    return string.indexOf(keyword.trim()) == -1 ? false : true
  });
  //return new RegExp('\\b' + keywords + '\\b', 'i').test(string);
}

console.log(wordInString(string, keywords))
console.log(wordInString(string, "xyz, abc"))
console.log(wordInString("'a large bear'", "large, none"))
```